# Background Removal not single solid color with magick.net

Tags: c#, imagemagick, photoshop

I am trying to use the magick.net library to remove the background of an image with a heterogeneous black background. However, the results have not been satisfied. The photo is still bordered at the same time, the black eye close to the background color is removed.

Here is the code I used:

```
var darkMark = image1.Clone();

darkMark.ColorFuzz = new Percentage(10);
darkMark.Transparent(new MagickColor("#111419"));
darkMark.Alpha(AlphaOption.Extract);
darkMark.Negate();

darkMark.Transparent(MagickColors.Black);
darkMark.Alpha(AlphaOption.Extract);
darkMark.Negate();

darkMark.Threshold(new Percentage(15));

image1.Composite(darkMark, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
image1.Write("bg.png");
```

Here is the root image:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image: result]

Here is the image I would like:

[image: like]

Answer (score 0):

You can add morphology close to your command in ImageMagick. In command line, I can do the following:

[image]

```
convert turtle.png -fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque black -morphology close diamond:1 x.png
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but with this command any same color with background will be remove like eye of turtle.

Comment: You would have to flood fill each region that you wanted to change to white. I know of no way to distinguish the eye from the holes in the text characters. How did you create the desired result image? If you have a method to do that, then just add the morphology to clean it up.